# Make Autoscaling own rule in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, autoscaling

it is possible to make own rule for auto scaling in AWS without using auto scaling menu in AWS console, but using a framework or something like that?? and if it possible, what can i use for make rule for auto scaling??

Answer (score 0):

Try the CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/index.html
You will need to configure credentials.

Comment: Thank you sir, i will try it